# RAID 1 scalability

Tags: raid, raid-1

Assuming I'm in a home environment and I want to keep my data secure, how would I build an expandable custom NAS? I can't afford a real SATA/SAS controller.

I'm thinking of a scalable array of RAID 1 disks, with cloud backups for the most sensitive data. If I begin my custom NAS setup with an array of 2 1TB disks, how can I expand it later? Can I do something like a JBOD of RAID 1 arrays?

Please, specify if the solution requires a hardware/fake controller or if it can be done with a software RAID.

I've been reading a lot, but I've never built a RAID array in a real scenario.

Comment: What sort of machine, what operating system, how is the existing set of drives configured?

Comment: what do you mean by "add?"  Do you want to replace the 1TB disks with the 2TB?

Comment: You can just create a second mirror with the 2TB drives, resulting on two arrays, one of 1TB (and two 1TB drives) and one with 2TB usable space (with two 2TB drives).  Which is something you can do both in software RAID, HW RAID and with fake RAID.

Comment: It is an assumption. As I said, that is for a home environment, so I can only afford a software RAID or a motherboard (fake) RAID. I need it to be extendable, because I can't get 4 or 6 disks at once. With "add" I'm saying "sum of capacity". I knew what @Hennes said, but it would result in two logical devices. There is not any better option? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assuming I'm in a home environment and I want to keep my data secure,
> how would I build an expandable custom NAS?
> I can't afford a real SATA/SAS controller.
>
> I'm thinking of a scalable array of RAID 1 disks, with cloud backups for
> the most sensitive data.

An external backup for the important data is a good start.
(No matter how well the NAS is build, is the house burns down all you have left is the external backup).

> If I begin my custom NAS setup with an array of 2 1TB disks,
> how can I expand it later?
> Can I do something like a JBOD of RAID 1 arrays?

I would use a different description than "a JBOD of RAID 1 arrays".
In almost any case you can add multiple RAID volumes to a system.
These would be independent arrays.

Basically you get one single array per RAID-1 mirror which acts just like a regular disk:

- But has faster reads (for two disks up to twice the read speed)
- And which writes the data to all drives in the array. Which means that you still have all the data until the last drive fails.
  (I wrote *last drive* since you can do RAID-1 with more than two drives. You do not get more capacity that way, but you do get more redundancy and more read speed).
- The RAID array acts just like a regular drive. You can partition it into a single volume or into multiple volumes (e.g. into a C:\ for the OS and a D:\ for data and documents).

You can use multiple RAID arrays.

- E.g. one RAID-1 with 2x1TB for 1TB capacity
  and one RAID-1 with 2x2TB for 2TB capacity.
  That way you do end up with two separate devices. Similar to using a regular 1TB and a regular 2TB drive.

You can combine RAID methods:
E.g:

- 2x1TB in a RAID-1 mirror as `array1`.
- 2x2TB in a RAID-1 mirror as `array2`.
- You can then create another RAID array 'array3' as a stripe of both array1 and array 2.
  That would yield a 3TB drive which seems to be what you are after.
  You will need to reinstall the OS though since you are starting with *a new drive*.

Note that not all read solution allow this. E.g. it will work fine with mdadm in Linux. It will work fine with FreeBSD. I have no idea how windows will handle it nor how a software RAID via the BIOS will handle it.

A third solution is this:

- Drive 1, one 1TB partition  (lets call it /dev/sda1)
- Drive 2, one 1TB partition  (lets call it /dev/sdb1)
- Drive 3, two 1TB partitions (lets call them /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdc2)
- Drive 4, two 1TB partitions (lets call them /dev/sdd1 /dev/sdd2)

Now you have a lot of options. E.g:

- A four way RAID-1E across /dev/sd{abcd}1. Awesome read performance.
- A RAID-5 across /dev/sd{abcd}1. Most capacity (3TB with another 2TB yet unused in /dev/sdc2 and /dev/sdd2). However RAID5 has poor performance for small writes.
  Read: Good for storing movies, isos, DVDs, etc etc. Bad for a database.
- ...

> Please, specify if the solution requires a hardware/fake controller
> or if it can be done with a software RAID.

There is no answer to this since it depends on the RAID implementation.
There is no hard limit why any of these solutions would not work with all three options (HW/SW/Fake RAID). However not all implementations may support it.

> I've been reading a lot, but I've never built a RAID array in a real scenario.

Try playing around with it a bit before committing your real data. But before you start I recommend [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them) as useful background information.

Personally I would do the following when building a typical home NAS:

1. Partition the two 1TB disk in at least two partitions:
   /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2 on the first disk,
   /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdb2 on the second disk.
2. Install the OS on the first partition. No RAID. No complications if you ever need to recover.
3. Backup the working OS to /dev/sdb1. Not as a mirror, but a once off copy to be used only in emergencies.
4. Make sure that you have working boot-loaders on both drives. E.g. remove or unplug the first drive and successfully boot from the OS on the second drive.
   If all goes well you will never need this backup OS again. Yet it is nice to have just in case and you do want to update it when you change the RAID configuration.
5. Create a mirror with the remaining space on the two 1TB drives. (Lets call it md1)
6. Partition md1 so you have volumes for SWAP and for /usr/local/.
7. Store your often accessed documents somewhere. E.g. in /usr/local/my_NAS_data.
8. Create a second array with the other two disks.
9. Mount this somewhere. E.g. /usr/local/my_NAS_data_part2/

If you have data which is not accessed often then put that in my_NAS_data_part2. When not in use you can let these two disks spin-down, saving electricity and creating less noise.

Writes (log-files and such) will still go to the first array/disk.

Comment: Thank you. With the second option, in the array3 (RAID 10) I'd lose 1TB, wouldn't I? Is the RAID 1E option better than a RAID 10 with (sda1 + sdb1) + (sdc1 + sdd1) + (sdc2 + sdd2)? Maybe you're right with your personal choice, there's no need for a single logical volume for everything since maybe I wouldn't fill more than 2TB with sentitive data (family videos/pictures, work, etc).

Comment: As long as you mirror everything you will always loose half the capacity. You simply write things down twice.  With RAID5 you do not do this. Instead you use one extra disk (at the cost of not gaining extra read speed). RAID5 is a good choice is you mainly read data (e.g. stream movies from a NAS), do not want to trade much capacity for redundancy and either have good backups or are willing to wait a long time if a disk fails. (Rebuilding a RAID5 array can be **SLOW**).

Comment: In non-home environments this is not a problem since the main goal tend to be to keep a RAID5 using file-server up till 5PM, and then do emergency maintenance (e.g. check and update backups, replace disk, do a relative quick restore from a backup). At home and without **full** off-site backups I would prefer a mirror. And I would try to keep things simple (e.g. two independent RAID-1 arrays and no RAID on the OS part).

Comment: Just to be complete: This is quite different from what I would recommend for aq work related setup. There I would use SAS rather than SATA. SAS tend to remain up if a disk fails. SATA fails less gratefully and you can expect the fileserver/NAS to hang if a disk fails. I am also aware of the price difference between [nearline] SAS and home equipment and I do use SATA disks myself for home setup. (With [TLER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_recovery_control) enabled).

Comment: I will have an independent disk for the OS (maybe a cheap 64GB SSD), a 2TB mirrored array for very sensitive data, an expandable JBOD/distributed array for other stuff (movies, ISOs...) and sync with Google Drive or similar for encrypted sensitive data (or compressed backups). I will be using Debian, Samba, FTP and Owncloud. Thank you very much for your help!